# Implementing machine learning API in Rust using elasticsearch8.4.0-alpha.1 library

Tags: elasticsearch, machine-learning, rust, rust-tokio

I am trying to implement machine learning API in **Rust** programming language using **elasticsearch8.4.0-alpha.1** library and now I am stuck. I want to use ML model which is already imported in Elasticsearch which converts text into vector. Please help me out.

```
pub async fn vector_search(data: web::Json<Value>) -> Result<HttpResponse, CustomError> {
    let client = get_client().unwrap();
    let infer_response = client
    .ml().get_trained_models(elasticsearch::ml::Ml::get_trained_models())
    .send()
    .await
    .unwrap();
    let response_id_body = infer_response.json::<Value>().await.unwrap();
    Ok(HttpResponse::Ok().json(json!(response_id_body)))
    
}
```